# Is it possible to build variable names from other variables in bash?

Tags: bash, variables

I apologise for the pretty terrible title - and the poor quality post - but what I basically want to do is this:

```
for I in 1 2 3 4
    echo $VAR$I # echo the contents of $VAR1, $VAR2, $VAR3, etc.
```

Obviously the above does not work - it will (I think) try and echo the variable called `$VAR$I` Is this possible in Bash?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, but don't do that. Use an array instead.

If you still insist on doing it that way...

```
$ foo1=123
$ bar=foo1
$ echo "${!bar}"
123
```

Comment: +1 for but don't do that. Use an array instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice re arrays. Using your and pax's post, I managed to get it working. Cheers guys.

Comment: it doesnt work for `kshell`

Answer (score 10):

```
for I in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    TMP="VAR$I"
    echo ${!TMP}
done
```

I have a general rule that if I need indirect access to variables (ditto arrays), then it is time to convert the script from shell into Perl/Python/etc. Advanced coding in shell though possible quickly becomes a mess.

Answer (score 5):

You should think about using `bash` arrays for this sort of work:

```
pax> set arr=(9 8 7 6)
pax> set idx=2
pax> echo ${arr[!idx]}
7
```

Answer (score 4):

For the case where you don't want to refactor your variables into arrays...

One way...

```
$ for I in 1 2 3 4; do TEMP=VAR$I ; echo ${!TEMP} ; done
```

Another way...

```
$ for I in 1 2 3 4; do eval echo \$$(eval echo VAR$I) ; done
```

I haven't found a simpler way that works.  For example, this does not work...

```
$ for I in 1 2 3 4; do echo ${!VAR$I} ; done
bash: ${!VAR$I}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Part of my answer was previously posted by @Dummy00001 -- the only person who had actually answered the question as asked.

Answer (score 3):

```
for I in {1..5}; do
    echo $((VAR$I))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html)

Comment: It would have been nice to transcribe some part of the linked page for direct understanding in your answer... but such a great reference!

Answer (score 0):

This definately looks like an array type of situation. Here's a link that has a very nice discussion (with many examples) of how to use arrays in bash: [Arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)