# Needs help on variable substitution in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am reading DB properties from databse.prop file and below is the code.

```
....
 for (( i=1;i<=$Dbcount;i++ ))
                        do
echo "$DBCONNECTIONNAME_${i}"                 
sqlplus -S ${user1}@$DBconnection_${i}/${Password} <<EOF &
spool sqlcsvdb_"$i".csv
                         @squery.sql $para1 $para2
                          exit
EOF
done
```

Properties file.
....

```
 DBcount=2
    user1=user
    Password=password
    DBconnection1=Connection1
    DBconnection2=Connection2
```

.....
I am getting the $DBconection_$i variable output as 1, 2 as looping and getting error message as bad substitution, plese help me on this.

Comment: This looks like a job for an array (or possibly indirect expansion, but an array's probably better). This is a possible duplicate of ["Is it possible to build variable names from other variables in bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963494/is-it-possible-to-build-variable-names-from-other-variables-in-bash) (which is marked as a duplicate of ["Dynamic variable names in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash), but you don't need an associative array). Also, see [BashFAQ #006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: ... Though a better solution if the suffix is a running number is to simply use an array. Bash 5+ has associative arrays, too.

Answer (score 1):

After `source "properties file"` you have the variables you want, and you can do

```
for ((i=1;i<=DBcount;i++)); do
   conn=DBconnection${i} # you need an extra var
   echo "${!conn}"
done
```

Another possibility is getting the value inside the loop:

```
for ((i=1;i<=$Dbcount;i++ )); do
   conn=$(sed -n "/DBconnection${i}=/ s/.*=//p" "properties file")
   echo "${conn}"
   sqlplus -S ${user1}@${conn}/${Password} <<EOF &
spool sqlcsvdb_"$i".csv
@squery.sql $para1 $para2
exit
EOF
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ Walter A